# Sending a tweet to somebody I follow but he doesn't follow me

Tags: twitter, tweet

Suppose I follow person B who doesn't follow me. If I want to send to person B a tweet of person C from an unrelated conversation, how do I do it? I tried "reply @B" but it didn't show the link. I tried "retweet" but I can only retweet to myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retweet (unless your account is protected) the tweet is publicly visible. If you mention someone in a tweet who does not follow you they will not receive an instant notification, but it will appear in their "Mentions and Interactions" tab.

So, if you quote the tweet of person C with a mention of @personB the tweet will appear in the Mentions and Interactions tab of personB

Twitter Support describes this in their ["Type of Tweets and where they appear"](https://support.twitter.com/articles/119138-types-of-tweets-and-where-they-appear)

> **Mentions:**
>
> **Definition:** A Tweet containing another user's Twitter username, preceded by the "@" symbol, like this: Hello @NeonGolden! What's up?
>   **Where it appears for the sender:** On the sender's profile page of public Tweets.
>
> **Where it appears for the recipient:** In the recipient's Mentions and Interactions tabs, which is accessible only by them. Additionally,
>   mentions will appear in the recipient's Home timeline view (not on
>   their profile) if they are following the sender. Note: Anyone on
>   Twitter who is following the sender of a mention will see the Tweet in
>   their Home timeline.
>
> **Places it will never appear:** On anyone's profile page, unless they wrote the message.

Comment: Not sure if this answer my question. I want to tweet (that is show all that tweet with possible links within it, the name of person C etc), not to just  copy paste a quote

Comment: You do show the name of the original tweeter in a retweet, but if it is too long with the added characters for the names of personB personC then you can use the link to the original tweet

Answer (score 1):

Each conversation has its own Twitter link which can be seen by hovering over Expand/Collapse or the other similar buttons. One thing I can do is to copy paste the link in a tweet to the person I wish to send.

Comment: You just answered your question correctly. This is the only way to "forward" the entire content of someone else's Tweet to a third person with an @ Also, it works whether you follow the third person or not.